# Oracle SQL merge half empty query lines

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle12 and a table

| Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| c1 | a1 |
| c2 | a1 |
| b2 | a2 |
| a2 | b3 |
| a2 | c2 |

no rows with `a%+a%` and `b%+b%`

I want to select 4 columns: `Debit+Credit` where exists `a% and not b%` in any column
and `Debit+Credit` where exists `a% and b%` in any column. The first column pair must correspond the second by `a%` value.

Something like

```
with t as (
  select 'a1' Debit, 'b1' Credit from dual
  union all select 'c1', 'a1' from dual
  union all select 'c2', 'a1' from dual
  union all select 'b2', 'a2' from dual
  union all select 'a2', 'b3' from dual
  union all select 'a2', 'c2' from dual)
select Debit, Credit, null DebitB, null CreditB
    from t
    where (Debit like 'a%' or Credit like 'a%')
    and (Debit not like 'b%' and Credit not like 'b%')
    union all
    select null, null, Debit, Credit
    from t
    where (Debit like 'a%' or Credit like 'a%')
    and (Debit like 'b%' or Credit like 'b%')
```

but merge (exclude empty cells if possible) these 6 rows into 4 "grouped" by `a%`. At first all merged rows with `a1`, then all merged rows with `a2` and so on. Any order within group, nulls last. The result must be

| Debit | Credit | DebitB | CreditB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | **a1** | **a1** | b1 |
| c2 | **a1** |  |  |
| **a2** | c2 | b2 | **a2** |
|  |  | **a2** | b3 |

Comment: What if there is `(a1, a2)`  row in the source table? Why `(a1 b1)` is merged with `(c1 a1)`, not `(c2 a1)` ?

Comment: there are no rows `(a, a)` or `(b, b)`, any order within group, nulls last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can number the rows and use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` matching on the `a` values and the row number:

```sql
SELECT t1.Debit,
       t1.Credit,
       t2.debit  AS DebitB,
       t2.credit AS CreditB
FROM   (
         SELECT t.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY CASE WHEN debit LIKE 'a%' THEN debit ELSE credit END
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN debit LIKE 'a%' THEN credit ELSE debit END
                ) AS rn
         FROM   t
         WHERE  debit LIKE 'a%' AND credit NOT LIKE 'b%'
         OR     debit NOT LIKE 'b%' AND credit LIKE 'a%'
       ) t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY CASE WHEN debit LIKE 'a%' THEN debit ELSE credit END
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN debit LIKE 'a%' THEN credit ELSE debit END
                ) AS rn
         FROM   t
         WHERE  debit LIKE 'a%' AND credit LIKE 'b%'
         OR     debit LIKE 'b%' AND credit LIKE 'a%'
       ) t2
       ON    CASE WHEN t1.debit LIKE 'a%' THEN t1.debit ELSE t1.credit END
             = CASE WHEN t2.debit LIKE 'a%' THEN t2.debit ELSE t2.credit END
          AND t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (debit, credit) as
  select 'a1', 'b1' from dual union all
  select 'c1', 'a1' from dual union all
  select 'c2', 'a1' from dual union all
  select 'b2', 'a2' from dual union all
  select 'a2', 'b3' from dual union all
  select 'a2', 'c2' from dual;
```

Outputs:

| DEBIT | CREDIT | DEBITB | CREDITB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | a1 | a1 | b1 |
| a2 | c2 | b2 | a2 |
| *null* | *null* | a2 | b3 |
| c2 | a1 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lx_iIPOP)

Comment: Not sure about `( t1.debit = t2.credit  AND t1.credit != t2.debit
          OR t1.debit != t2.credit AND t1.credit =  t2.debit )` . I would rather used a partition key =  `case when Debit like 'a%' then Debit else Credit end` in the full join.

Comment: @Serg For the OP's sample data they both work but its not clear whether they want to only match `t1.credit = t2.debit` and vice-versa or if they also want to match `t1.credit = t2.credit` (and same for debit) as that use-case does not appear in the sample data. I've updated to use your `CASE` suggestion as it is the more generic option but the OP can look at the previous edit if they only want to match credit/debit pairs from different tables.